# After importing about 130 informix databases I get error

Tags: database, informix

I have the following problem:

I have a default Informix database with many tables.
I used the command dbexport to export that database to disk.

After that, I imported about 130 databases from that export.

I end up with the following error which I cannot solve:

```
212: Cannot add index.
136: ISAM error: no more extents
```

I also end up with the error when I try to insert a new table in one database.
It then says:

```
TblSpace - No more pages.
```

I can insert data in a table without any problems.

Anything what I can do to get around that?

I want to import about 10.000 of these databases.

Comment: Seems you have run out of space on your Informix instance.

Comment: Ive added more database-space files to get around that, but i still have enough space :/

Comment: The problem is probably that you have reached a limit in the 'tblspace tblspace' in the root chunk of the root dbspace.  Have you determined how much space each of your 10,000 databases will need?  Do you have enough disk space for that plus the metadata (such as the information stored in the tblspace tblspace, not to mention the system databases such as sysmaster, sysuser, sysutils, sysadmin)?  Have you considered creating multiple dbspaces, and placing sets of 100 or 1000 databases into each dbspace?  How much will the databases grow?  Are you sure that 10,000 databases is the right design?

Comment: Have you looked at tenant databases?  They might, or might not, be relevant to you.

Comment: Searching Google for 'informix tblspace' comes up with [What is TBLspace TBLspace](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21174940) (dated 2004 but still basically valid) and [Tblspaces](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_11.70.0/com.ibm.admin.doc/ids_admin_0525.htm) (from the 11.70 documentation, but it hasn't changed significantly in 12.10 or 14.10).